# Patreon Oauth API

Tags: javascript, oauth, patreon

I am trying to use the Patreon API.

I already have the Client ID and the Client Secret etc.

When I open the oauth url with the client id and client secret passed into it. e.g.

```
var url = 'https://www.patreon.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=' + clientid +'&redirect_uri=' + redirecturl +'&scope=<optional list of requested scopes>&state=<optional string>'
```

I do not get to page that allows me to login with my Patreon account but instead I go to the redirect URL with some parameters passed into it:

e.g.
http://localhost:3000/?error=invalid_scope&state=%3Coptional+string%3E

What does this mean and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error=invalid_scope` usually [means](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1) that the value of parameter `scope` in your request was incorrect. This parameter is optional, so you can easily omit it.

But if you need some custom scope, [documentation](https://docs.patreon.com/#step-2-making-the-log-in-button) suggests writing to Patreon support.

Comment: Hi You are right....I removed the scope and state parameter and now it is working...

Comment: Now I get a code passed into the redirect url e.g. http://localhost:3000/?code=uPp3vLLUcA2w6VNmrKzKkkdblPaJi9&state=None  How do I use that code using Javascript????

Comment: @preston I'd suggest doing it on serverside (not to make client_secret public) or using ```response_type=token```.

Comment: Hi. How do we add scpe (users pledges-to-me my-campaign) to the URL. How do we count for the spaces, etc ? This wont work...
&scope=users pledges-to-me my-campaign&redire.....

Comment: @GaddMaster Hi, you should urlencode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your param values: `&scope=users%20pledges-to-me%20my-campaign&redire...`